# FirebaseError: Firebase: firebase.messaging() takes either no argument or a Firebase App instance. (app/invalid-app-argument)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I try to get firebase messaging token on flutter web using code below, I get error outlined in the title of the question, that firebase messaging takes no arguments or firebase app as an argument

```
try {
    print(await messaging.getToken(vapidKey: kIsWeb ? VAPID_KEY : null));
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these versions:

```
  firebase_messaging: ^13.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.22.0
```